# .net core mvc 6 (razor) не английские символы автоматом переводятся в Unicode Hex Character

Tags: razor, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

В .net core в представлениях (Razor) теперь все НЕ английские символы автоматически конвертируются в соотвествующий хекс код.

и теперь весь русский текст, который берётся из модели, или из переменных и пр. будут выглядеть как:

```
&#x41C;&#x44B; &#x43D;&#x435; #x441;&#x43C;&#x43E; ...
```

И чтоб получить нормальный текст на русском нужно её значение выводить используя Html.Raw()

тоесть если я в контроллере присвою переменной

```
string txt="текст на русском";
```

и в представлении напишу

```
Смотрите это: @txt
```

то в html разметке я увижу:

```
смотрите это:  &#x41C;&#x44B;&#x43D;&#x435;#x441;&#x43C;&#x43E;&#x436;&#x435;&#x43C;
```

Если же использовать стандартные структуры типа

```
<input id="chk-parts-agree" asp-for="Agree" class="form-check-input"/>
```

то из модели весь текст с валидацией на русском автоматом преобразуется и получим

```
<input class="form-check-input" data-val="true" data-val-required="&#x41C;&#x44B; &#x43D;&#x435; &#x441;&#x43C;&#x43E;&#x436;&#x435;&#x43C; &#x441;&#x432;&#x44F;&#x437;&#x430;&#x442;&#x44C;&#x441;&#x44F; &#x441; &#x432;&#x430;&#x43C;&#x438;, &#x435;&#x441;&#x43B;&#x438; &#x432;&#x4#x44B; &#x43D;&#x435; &#x434;&#x430;&#x434;&#x438;&#x442;&#x435; &#x441;&#x43E;&#x433;&#x43B;&#x430;&#x441;&#x438;&#x435; &#x43D;&#x430; &#x445;&#x440;&#x430;&#x43D;&#x435;&#x43D;&#x438;&#x435; &#x438; &#x43E;&#x431;&#x440;&#x430;&#x431;&#x43E;&#x442;&#x43A;&#x443; &#x432;&#x430;&#x448;&#x438;&#x445; &#x43F;&#x435;&#x440;&#x441;&#x43E;&#x43D;&#x430;&#x43B;&#x44C;&#x43D;&#x44B;&#x445; &#x434;&#x430;&#x43D;&#x43D;&#x44B;&#x445; (&#x422;&#x435;&#x43B;&#x435;&#x444;&#x43E;&#x43D; &#x438; &#x424;&#x418;&#x41E;)" id="chk-service-agree" name="Agree"  type="checkbox" value="true" />
```

конечно для конечного пользователя ничего не изменится и на страничке он видит правильный русский текст, однако сам html заметно растет.

Как "обьяснить" .net core, что символы латинские "не опасны" и не нужно их заменять при выводе вместе с символами "&<> и т.п. ?

В общем сделать так как было раньше...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

в файле Startup.cs

в

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ....
    //Чтобы кирилические символы не переводились в соответствующий Unicode Hex Character Code
    services.Configure<WebEncoderOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.TextEncoderSettings = new TextEncoderSettings(UnicodeRanges.All);
    });
}
```

Comment: Автор супер +++ выручил не представляешь как

Comment: Сам кучу времени убил ;-)