# ViewData выводит на страницу представления данные в кодировке

Tags: c#, mvc, .net-core

Я вывожу данные в представление через ViewData, примерный код:

```js
 if (ViewData["post"] != null)
        {
            var post = ViewData["post"] as PostFull;
            string keywords = "";
            post.passage = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(post.passage, "<[^>]+>", string.Empty);

            <title>@post.title</title>
            <meta name="title" content="@post.title">
            <meta name="description" content="@post.passage">

            foreach (var tg in post.tags)
            {
                keywords += tg[1] + ",";
            }
            <meta name="keywords" content="@keywords">
        }
```

и на выходе имею:

```html
<title>&amp;#x41F;&amp;#x435;&amp;#x440;&amp;#x432;&amp;#x43E;&amp;#x43D;&amp;#x430;&amp;#x447;&amp;#x430;&amp;#x43B;&amp;#x44C;&amp;#x43D;&amp;#x430;&amp;#x44F; &amp;#x43D;&amp;#x430;&amp;#x441;&amp;#x442;&amp;#x440;&amp;#x43E;&amp;#x439;&amp;#x43A;&amp;#x430; Brocade ICX 6450, Ruckus ICX 7150</title>
```

данные в класс PostFull собираются из БД. При этом если выводить @html.raw то выводится все нормально, но по мне это как-то не правильно. Сам браузер в обоих случаях отображает как надо, но в исходном коде HTML вот такие крякозябры.

Как мне это побороть?

Answer (score 2):

У Вас в `post.title`, не текст `"Первоначальная настройка"`, а вот такое его закодированное представление: `"&#x41F;&#x435;&#x440;&#x432;..."`. Вы где-то уже один раз обработали этот текст для вывода в HTML, a Razor `@` делает это еще раз.

Или сделайте так, чтобы в `post.title` был нормальный текст, или действительно выводите его через `raw`.

```html
<div>&#x41F;&#x435;&#x440;&#x432;&#x43E;&#x43D;&#x430;&#x447;&#x430;&#x43B;&#x44C;&#x43D;&#x430;&#x44F; &#x43D;&#x430;&#x441;&#x442;&#x440;&#x43E;&#x439;&#x43A;&#x430; Brocade ICX 6450, Ruckus ICX 7150</div>
```

Comment: для эксперимента я в самом представлении объявляю string ff="привет"; и тут же его вывожу @ff - и получаю такие же кракозябры

Comment: Я предполагаю, что этому Razor я должен где-то в настройках сказать, чтоб он дружил с кириллицей, а не пытался ее преобразовывать

Answer (score 1):

Вот правильные ответ на мой вопрос.
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/662453/332107

```js
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ....
    //Чтобы кирилические символы не переводились в соответствующий Unicode Hex Character Code
    services.Configure<WebEncoderOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.TextEncoderSettings = new TextEncoderSettings(UnicodeRanges.All);
    });
}
```